# Подключение скриптов через functions.php на Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Необходимо подключить скрипт jquery, в интернете много разной информации, хочу убедиться, что все правильно понял. Это правильный код, все будет работать корректно?

```
add_action ( 'wp_footer', 'GetScripts' );
function GetScripts () {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('init', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/init.js', array('jquery'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, скрипты нужно подключать через хук `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'GetScripts' );
function GetScripts () {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js', array(), false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'init', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/init.js', array('jquery'), false, true );
}
```

5-ый параметр функции `wp_enqueue_script`, установленый в `true`, позволяет задать загрузку скрипта в футере.

Comment: Так а почему нельзя через хук wp_footer? Так принято?

Comment: Да, так неправильно, так как через этот хук грузятся скрипты плагинов, соблюдается очередность загрузки и прочее.
Если игнорировать рекомендуемый способ подключения скриптов, то нет гарантии, что у вас не сломается что-то.

Comment: Исправь ошибку. Этот хук для скриптов. Для стилей - wp_enqueue_style